# Sorting an array of coordinates by their distance from origin

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

The code should take an array of coordinates from the user, then sort that array, putting the coordinates in order of their distance from the origin. I believe my problem lies in the sorting function (I have used a quicksort).

I am trying to write the function myself to get a better understanding of it, which is why I'm not using `qsort()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 64

typedef struct
{
    double x, y;
}POINT;

double distance(POINT p1, POINT p2);
void sortpoints(double distances[MAX_SIZE], int firstindex, int lastindex, POINT data[MAX_SIZE]);
void printpoints(POINT data[], int n_points);

int main()
{    
    int n_points, i;
    POINT data[MAX_SIZE], origin = { 0, 0 };
    double distances[MAX_SIZE];

    printf("How many values would you like to enter?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n_points);

    printf("enter your coordinates\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n_points; i++)
    {
        scanf("%lf %lf", &data[i].x, &data[i].y);
        distances[i] = distance(data[i], origin); //data and distances is linked by their index number in both arrays
    }

    sortpoints(distances, 0, i, data);

    return 0;
}

double distance(POINT p1, POINT p2)
{
    return sqrt(pow((p1.x - p2.x), 2) + pow((p1.y - p2.y), 2));
}

void printpoints(POINT *data, int n_points)
{
    int i;

    printf("Sorted points (according to distance from the origin):\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n_points; i++)
    {
        printf("%.2lf %.2lf\n", data[i].x, data[i].y);
    }
}

//quicksort
void sortpoints(double distances[MAX_SIZE], int firstindex, int lastindex, POINT data[MAX_SIZE])
{
    int indexleft = firstindex;
    int indexright = lastindex;
    int indexpivot = (int)((lastindex + 1) / 2);
    int n_points = lastindex + 1;
    double left = distances[indexleft];
    double right = distances[indexright];
    double pivot = distances[indexpivot];
    POINT temp;

    if (firstindex < lastindex) //this will halt the recursion of the sorting function once all the arrays are 1-size
    {

        while (indexleft < indexpivot || indexright > indexpivot) //this will stop the sorting once both selectors reach the pivot position
        {
            //reset the values of left and right for the iterations of this loop
            left = distances[indexleft];
            right = distances[indexright];

            while (left < pivot)
            {
                indexleft++;
                left = distances[indexleft];
            }

            while (right > pivot)
            {
                indexright--;
                right = distances[indexright];
            }

            distances[indexright] = left;
            distances[indexleft] = right;

            temp = data[indexleft];
            data[indexleft] = data[indexright];
            data[indexright] = temp;
        }

        //recursive sorting to sort the sublists
        sortpoints(distances, firstindex, indexpivot - 1, data);
        sortpoints(distances, indexpivot + 1, lastindex, data);
    }

    printpoints(data, n_points);
}
```

Thanks for your help, I have been trying to debug this for hours, even using a debugger.

Comment: Why are you not using `qsort()`? http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/qsort.html

Comment: Use a debugger instead of posting 100+ lines of code

Comment: If you don't know if your sorting implementation is the problem, then perhaps you should exchange it for something simpler (e.g. bubble sort), so that you can _know_ if that is your problem...

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something more meaningful. As it is, it provides no information about your question, and it is absolutely meaningless for future readers trying to search for help for their problem in the future. While you're at it, you can provide more info about what "does not run" means. You have not asked a question here, and "does not run" means nothing to anyone except you. Please explain the **specific** problem. Thanks.

Comment: Just a point: although it is semantically correct, I'd use `n_points` instead of `i` when calling `sortpoints()`. The later keeps the code clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Ouch! You call `sortpoints()` with `i` as argument. That argument, according to your prototype and code, should be the `last index`, and `i` is not the `last index`, but the `last index + 1`.

```
int indexleft = firstindex;
int indexright = lastindex;   // indexright is pointing to a non-existent element.
int indexpivot = (int)((lastindex + 1) / 2);
int n_points = lastindex + 1;
double left = distances[indexleft];
double right = distances[indexright];  // now right is an undefined value, or segfault.
```

To fix that, call your `sortpoints()` function as:

```
 sortpoints (0, n_points-1, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `sortpoints` function.  The first `while` loop is looping infinitely. To test that is it an infinite loop or not place a `printf` statement

```
printf("Testing first while loop\n");
```

in your first `while` loop. You have to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a number of problems, but one of them is:

```
int indexpivot = (int)((lastindex + 1) / 2);
```

The cast is unnecessary, but that's trivia.  Much more fundamental is that if you are sorting a segment from, say, 48..63, you will be pivoting on element 32, which is not in the range you are supposed to be working on.  You need to use:

```
int indexpivot = (lastindex + firstindex) / 2;
```

or perhaps:

```
int indexpivot = (lastindex + firstindex + 1) / 2;
```

For the example range, these will pivot on element 55 or 56, which is at least within the range.

I strongly recommend:

- Creating a print function similar to `printpoints()` but with the following differences:

  1. Takes a 'tag' string to identify what it is printing.
  2. Takes and prints the distance array too.
  3. Takes the arrays and a pair of offsets.
- Use this function inside the sort function before recursing.
- Use this function inside the sort function before returning.
- Use this function in the main function after you've read the data.
- Use this function in the main function after the data is sorted.
- Print key values — the pivot distance, the pivot index, at appropriate points.

This allows you to check that your partitioning is working correctly (it isn't at the moment).

Then, when you've got the code working, you can remove or disable (comment out) the printing code in the sort function.